# Percentages of dollar value

Tags: correlation, categorical-data

Attempting to perform data analysis on property prices in a given region to find the average value of a certain land type. For example:

Property A
Value: $1,000,000
Land area: 1000 ha
Land type A: 34%
Land type B: 48%
Land type C: 18%

Property B
Value: $2,000,000
Land area: 3000 ha
Land type A: 14%
Land type B: 23%
Land type C: 63%

Is this data sufficient to find the average value per ha of an individual land type? If so, how? If not, what other data would be necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need at least one more relationship among the price of two land types. Let A, B and C be the prices (in thousands), you have:

```
340 A + 480 B + 180 C = 1000
420 A + 690 B + 1890 C = 2000
#simplifying  
17 A + 24 B + 9 C = 50
42 A + 69 B + 189 C = 200
```

With Gaussian elimination you get:

```
A + (-261/11)C = -90/11
B + (189/11)C = 260/33
```